# Is there any logic behind how will bonuses get added each rank?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I noticed that each soldier gets different will bonuses every promotion. Does this depend on something specific in the mission such as kills or actions, or is it completely random? Does every soldier have their own predetermined will bonuses?

-- ADDED FOR CLARITY --

What I have seen is that all rookies start with a will of 40 (from my limited sample size at the start of the game). Once you get the "new guy" perk that allows specializations for new recruits their will can get bumped anywhere from +1 to +10 points (up to 50 is the highest I've seen on a soldier with 0 missions). From there, every rank seems to grant some amount of will points which either differ by soldier or by something else.

I'm wondering if some soldiers are just more gifted than others and generally get larger bonuses or if it's something mission specific that determines it. I have a colonel that has a will of 90 and another that has only 75. Now, some of this is probably due to the perk that grants larger will bonuses, but I haven't seen any numbers on this. Any info related to will progress would be great. I'm trying to build a psi army.

Comment: are you really seeing different will upgrades as in, write down number before and afterwards, or are you simply seeing different will values for soldiers of the same rank (due to having different starting will values)?

Comment: I haven't put much time into researching it specifically, but what I seem to have noticed is that some soldiers get higher will bonuses each rank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Soldiers_%28EU2012%29#Ranks) is a description of promotion bonuses. The wiki says each soldier gains 2-6 Will per promotion, plus another 2-6 if Iron Will is researched...

**BUT**

Looking into a magic file of `DefaultGameCore.ini`, I see:

```
iRandWillIncrease=6
iBaseOTSWillIncrease=2
iRandOTSWillIncrease=4
...blah blah each class gets +2 will each rank
```

This suggests that it is 2-8 Will per rank without Iron Will, and 4-14 with. Does it correspond with everyone's experience?

Comment: the base will of each soldier differs, for rookies I've seen anywhere from 42-47 (don't recall if I've seen a rookie with a starting will of 41).  Also, there's a upgraded that increases the will gained per rank.

Comment: It seems that all rookies start with a will of 40, but once you get  the "new guy" perk it can bump new recruits all the way up to 50 (that's as high as i've seen it for soldiers with 0 missions).

I have a few captains who are already in the 70s on will, and that can't be from getting 2 points every rank, doesn't add up.

Comment: @maxx yea, sorry, I meant after the first upgrade.  You are right the new rookie always starts at 40.  The 'new guy' perk, in combination with the extra will per rank up perk, boosts squaddies up to 52.  I think the rank up perk makes the will gain per rank equal to 5 instead of 2.

Comment: Given that the reported max will is 50 for a squaddie pre-Iron Will, and 52 with Iron Will, either Iron Will gives +2 will per rank, or there's something more complicated going on than the current theory on the wiki.